# Two Kernel Panics in two weeks, what's wrong?

Tags: kernel, kernel-panic

I've had two kernel panics in two weeks on my Macbook.

Any idea what's wrong?

Here's my report:

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  386578 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          2
Anonymous UUID:                    09701575-AE25-4724-B99B-006ED35D39E3

Wed Feb 22 13:33:08 2012
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff80002c266d): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f8115c33d, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffff8015d47000, CR3: 0x0000000000100000, CR4: 0x00000000000606e0
RAX: 0xffffff8015d47000, RBX: 0xffffff806c1741e1, RCX: 0xffffffffffffffff, RDX: 0xffffff8015d46ff2
RSP: 0xffffff807edfacf0, RBP: 0xffffff807edfad40, RSI: 0x0000000000000400, RDI: 0x0000000000000000
R8:  0xffffff807edfad7c, R9:  0xffffff807edfb444, R10: 0xffffff8015d46c00, R11: 0xffffff8015d46c00
R12: 0xffffff8015d46c00, R13: 0x0000000000000001, R14: 0xffffff800f533000, R15: 0x0000000000000000
RFL: 0x0000000000010296, RIP: 0xffffff7f8115c33d, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
CR2: 0xffffff8015d47000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Faulting CPU: 0x2

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff807edfa9b0 : 0xffffff8000220702 
0xffffff807edfaa30 : 0xffffff80002c266d 
0xffffff807edfabd0 : 0xffffff80002d7a1d 
0xffffff807edfabf0 : 0xffffff7f8115c33d 
0xffffff807edfad40 : 0xffffff7f8115c567 
0xffffff807edfadb0 : 0xffffff7f8115c6b0 
0xffffff807edfae40 : 0xffffff7f81159efc 
0xffffff807edfb2d0 : 0xffffff7f8115bc70 
0xffffff807edfb360 : 0xffffff7f811589c7 
0xffffff807edfb3c0 : 0xffffff7f8115647b 
0xffffff807edfb4f0 : 0xffffff8000596c30 
0xffffff807edfb540 : 0xffffff8000583a2a 
0xffffff807edfb570 : 0xffffff80003c8636 
0xffffff807edfbbc0 : 0xffffff80003bd9be 
0xffffff807edfbc10 : 0xffffff80003bf505 
0xffffff807edfbdb0 : 0xffffff80003bf67d 
0xffffff807edfbdd0 : 0xffffff8000361f10 
0xffffff807edfbe00 : 0xffffff8000346860 
0xffffff807edfbe90 : 0xffffff8000341221 
0xffffff807edfbec0 : 0xffffff8000345b86 
0xffffff807edfbf60 : 0xffffff8000340e79 
0xffffff807edfbfb0 : 0xffffff8000820057 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.Cvnt.nke(2.0)[D47DD480-CCB5-6EEF-1164-A353001FBE0A]@0xffffff7f81155000->0xffffff7f8116afff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
11D50b

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 11.3.0: Thu Jan 12 18:47:41 PST 2012; root:xnu-1699.24.23~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 7B6546C7-70E8-3ED8-A6C3-C927E4D3D0D6
System model name: MacBookPro8,1 (Mac-94245B3640C91C81)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 222761929996886
last loaded kext at 221006212581276: com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  3.0.3 (addr 0xffffff7f80a48000, size 86016)
last unloaded kext at 206145571682808: com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver    4.0.3f12 (addr 0xffffff7f80915000, size 73728)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  3.1.2
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  3.1.2
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 3.1.2
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 3.1.2
com.vmware.kext.vmnet   3.0.0
com.vmware.kext.vmioplug    3.0.0
com.vmware.kext.vmci    3.0.0
com.vmware.kext.vmx86   3.0.0
com.Cvnt.driver.CvntDriver  1.5
com.Cvnt.nke    2.0
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 1.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelProfile  85.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.4d0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.59
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.9
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.0.26
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.1.7f9
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.1.7f9
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   7.1.8
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.42
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.1d2
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.1d2
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AudioIPCDriver 1.2.2
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    4.7.5d4
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.5.3
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.1.9
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  225.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  312
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 225.2
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.0.3
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 33
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    4.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.8.9
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   513.20.19
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.0.8b2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   4.5.8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 167.3.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   3.2.30
com.apple.security.quarantine   1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   167.3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileTimestampAction    85.2
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileThreadInfoAction   85.2
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileRegisterStateAction    85.2
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileReadCounterAction  85.2
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileKEventAction   85.2
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileCallstackAction    85.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily  85.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAVBAudio  1.0.0d11
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.1.7f9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.10d0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   80.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.0.3f12
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 1.0.0d22
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.1.7f9
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.1.7f9
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.6fc6
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.3
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.0.16
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.1d8
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 4.7.5d4
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.0.16
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraph
Model: MacBookPro8,1, BootROM MBP81.0047.B24, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.4 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.68f98
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 384 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353737334448302D4348392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353737334448302D4348392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.100.98.75.19)
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.3f12, 2 service, 11 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA MK5065GSXF, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-8A8
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8509, 0xfa200000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: LG Android USB Device, 0x1004  (LG Electronics Inc.), 0x61ce, 0xfa130000 / 6
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0252, 0xfa120000 / 5
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 4
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x821a, 0xfa113000 / 9
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd110000 / 3
```

Comment: I'd say this is not a real question, hence the downvote (I didn't do it).

Comment: why is it not a real question?

Comment: You've given technical data, but you haven't given much information about the background of the problem.  What significant changes in software or hardware, if any, have occurred recently?  What were you doing just before the kernel panicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an access violation in the kernel-mode part of the bluetooth driver. It is caused by an invalid memory access from kernel mode which is a serious programming flaw in how the driver has been written. (Specifically the processor tried to read the memory at 0xffffff8015d47000 which was unmapped).

Unfortunately there is nothing specific you can do to prevent this type of crash, however if the bug continues to occur, you may find that turning off your bluetooth devices will make the system more stable.

In the meantime, ensure that crash-dumps are being sent back to Apple and at some point they will be able to fix and release a patch for the broken driver.